# What is the difference between (this as IFoo<string>).Do() and just this.Do() in the following code?

Tags: c#

I often find as in [ArrayMarkupExtension.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/ArrayExtension.cs), people do casting that seems to me to be trivial.

Consider the simplified version as follows.

What is the difference between `(this as IFoo<string>).Do()` and just `this.Do()` in the following code?

```
interface IFoo
{
    object Do();
}

interface IFoo<out T> : IFoo
{
    new T Do();
}

class Something : IFoo<string>
{
    public string Do()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }

    object IFoo.Do()
    {
        //return this.Do();
        return (this as IFoo<string>).Do();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do they both work? I'd guess so, and they should both generate the same IL?

Comment: I'm guessing the `as IFoo<string>` was used to hammer home that it's calling the `Do` method implemented on the generic interface.

Comment: Add a method string IFoo<string>.Do() { return "I do"; } and then check both again

Comment: @OnlyTheParanoidSurvive You have to use `IFoo foo = new Something(); Console.WriteLine(foo.Do())` and only then you will see *Something" or "I do"

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Maybe the internal details and the casting impact on performance.

Comment: You can look at the IL as well as anyone else and see what difference there is in the "internal details", and you could test to see whether there's any impact on performance. Indeed, _only_ you can do that, because the performance impact (if any) is relevant only the context of your code. What part of this question is something that _you_ cannot answer yourself? What have you done already to try to answer that part, and what _specifically_ are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood it.

- `(this as IFoo<string>).Do();` invokes `string IFoo<string>.Do() => "IFoo<string>.Do()";` if it is available. Otherwise, it invokes `public string Do() => "Do()";`.
- `this.Do();` can only invoke `public string Do() => "Do()";`

The complete code:

```
interface IFoo
{
    object Do();
}

interface IFoo<out T> : IFoo
{
    new T Do();
}

class Something : IFoo<string>
{
    string IFoo<string>.Do() => "IFoo<string>.Do()";

    public string Do() => "Do()";

    //object IFoo.Do() => (this as IFoo<string>).Do();

    object IFoo.Do() => this.Do();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo<string> x = new Something();
        Console.WriteLine(x.Do());
    }
}
```